# Where does the "call" function used in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, keras, call

I am writing a RESNET but I can not understand where does the "call" function is used.

Maybe this is automatically called by the TensorFlow, so it means we must write a function named "call"? If so, what should be the exact requirement for this "call" function? Thank you!!

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Sequential

class BasicBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filter_num, strides=1):
        super(BasicBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filter_num, (3, 3), strides=strides, padding="same")
        self.bn1 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.relu = layers.Activation('relu')
        self.conv2 = layers.Conv2D(filter_num, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same")
        self.bn2 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        if strides != 1:
            self.downsample = layers.Conv2D(filter_num, (1, 1), strides=strides)
        else:
            self.downsample = lambda x:x

    def call(self, inputs, training=None): 
        out = self.conv1(inputs)
        out = self.bn1(out, training=training)
        out = self.relu(out)

        out = self.conv2(out, training=training)
        out = self.bn2(out)

        identity = self.downsample(inputs)

        output = layers.add([out, identity])
        output = tf.nn.relu(output)

        return output
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define a custom layer you will extend the base class `tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer` and use it as follow:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class BasicBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
   ...

basic_block = BasicBlock()
basic_block(inputs)
```

The last line of the snippet just above will call the magic method `__call__` from the class (more info on magic methods here if you are interested [A Guide to Python's Magic Methods](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/))

Since you did not define the `__call__` method in `BasicBlock` (you defined the `call` which is different), the `__call__` from `tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer` will be used.

This method has the following documentation according to [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer?version=nightly#__call__)

> Wraps call, applying pre- and post-processing steps.

Roughly speaking you will have (you can check the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L918) if you are interested but it is much more complex):

```
class Layer(...):
   ....
   def __call__(self, ...):
      # preprocessing steps
      self.call(...)
      # post processing steps
```

If you are familiar with inheritance you should guess the different steps when you use `basic_block(inputs)`:

1. Check if `BasicBlock` has a method named `__call__` => No
2. Check if the base class `Layer` has a method named `__call__` => Yes, use it and go inside this method
3. Apply the preprocessing steps
4. Check if `BasicBlock` has a method named `call` => Yes, use it and apply it to the inputs
5. Apply the post processing steps

---

Regarding the requirements of the `call` method to implement the best resource is the [official Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer?version=nightly#call) where you have everything explained about the input data structures expected + keyword arguments

Answer (score 0):

The call function is used in the following manner:

```
basic_block = BasicBlock()
basic_block(args)
```

so it comes instead of:

```
basic_block.call(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow, the **call()** method of a custom model is automatically called when you invoke the model instance as a function with input data. This is typically done using the **parentheses () operator**, which is a shorthand for calling the call() method.

For example, in the code provided in the question:

```
basicblock = BasicBlock(filter_num)
basicblock(input_data) # this will invoke the call method
```

It looks like this:

```
BasicBlock(filter_num)(input_data)
```